# Excel Formula or someway to split string character by character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In cell "A1" i have the string : "UIJKLQERAD"

I would like to split it character by character:

[image]

Is there any formula or someway i can use for it?

Comment: Use `MID` and `COLUMN`. But you should not hardcode the input string, thus reserve a cell for it. Pay attention to the end of the string.

Comment: Of course, you can use VBA to achieve exactly what you did above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of formula works, however it is using a dedicated cell as input:

`=MID($A$1; COLUMN();1)`

[image]

Note: this screenshot is from *google docs*, but it is the same in *Excel* and others.